# Не отображается документация FastAPI сервиса по запросу http://127.0.0.1:8000/docs

Tags: python, fastapi, swaggerui

Пробую тестово запустить веб-сервис, написанный на FastAPI.
Написал небольшой кусок кода:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI

app = FastAPI()

@app.get("/")
async def root():
    return {"message": "Hello, NDO AutoRoutine!"}
```

При указании http://127.0.0.1:8000/ вижу текст "Hello, NDO AutoRoutine!".
Тут все хорошо.

Но при попытке посмотреть документацию, которую генерирует Swagger, вижу пустую страницу.
Прохожу по ссылке http://127.0.0.1:8000/docs

В панели разработчика отображается это:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Каким образом можно это исправить, чтобы документация отображалась корректно?

Comment: Насколько я вижу, у вас не подгружается js код сваггера (12 строка). Попробуйте открыть скрипт вручную в браузере